# How to make scale background zooming only on image (not on child elements)

Tags: jquery, css, scale, zooming

Below is my example. Maybe anyone else has the same issue. For example my `div` named `.description-container` is moving together with the main container `.one-more-container`.

```js
$('div').removeClass('one-more-container');
```

```css
.one-more-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.one-more-container .single-featured-background {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  transition: all 3s;
}

.single-featured-background {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
  transition: all 3s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one-more-container">
<div id="post" class="single-featured-background" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb['0'];?>')">
    <div class="super-title-container">
        <h1 class="super-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <div class="description-container">
            <h2><?php the_field('antraste'); ?></h2>
            <p><?php the_field('aprasymas'); ?></p>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a separate element only for background. And you can animate that element only.

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  $('div').removeClass('one-more-container');
},3000);
```

```css
.one-more-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.single-featured-background {
  position:relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.onlyBg{  
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
  transition: all 3s;
}

.one-more-container .onlyBg {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: all 3s;
}

.super-title-container{
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one-more-container">
<div id="post" class="single-featured-background" >
    <div class="onlyBg" style="background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150')"></div>
    <div class="super-title-container">
        <h1 class="super-title">title</h1>
        <div class="description-container">
            <h2>sub title</h2>
            <p>paragraph</p>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you really don't need jquery to achieve this effect

Comment: fair enough but isn't it good to show new devs that you can do a lot of stuff with pure css?